# Error When Trying to Do Boolean Method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using the book "Head First Java Second Edition" to lean the language but when typing the example in Eclipse it will not let me use Boolean methods without giving an error. What is the proper way to initialize a Boolean method with Java using Eclipse? This is what I have entered:

```
public class BeerSong {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";

        While (beerNum > 0);


            If (beerNum == 1); {
                word = "bottle";
            }

            System.out.println(beerNum + " "+ word + " of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(beerNum + " "+ word + " of beer.");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;

            If (beerNum > 0); {
                System.out.println (beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
          } 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: java is case sensitive

Comment: There is no Boolean (or boolean) method in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while`, `if` is the correct spelling (no upper case there). Also do NOT append a "`;`" after an `if`, because that end's the block.

```
if (beerNum > 0) {
    System.out.println (beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
} else {
    System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
}
```

Notice the missing semicolon in the line of the first if block. Same goes for the semicolons in the other if and while statements.

if (...) executes the following block, but a semicolon makes that an empty block, thus...

```
if ( something ); { 
    doSomething 
}
```

is equivalent to...

```
if (something ) {
  // do absolutely nothing here
}
doSomething;
```

...because the if block executes ";" (nothing, instead of the doSomething block) and after that, in any case, the block with the doSomething is executed. So, no semicolon after `if`, `while`, etc.